# direction of current densities for electrons and holes?

Tags: electromagnetism, semiconductors, solid-state-devices

Let's say we have:

\$ J_n = 3 \frac{A}{m^2} \$ and \$ J_p = 2 \frac{A}{m^2} \$

and let's define the direction of positive current (flow of positive charges) to be moving from left to right. Then, would \$ J_n = 3 \frac{A}{m^2} \$ mean that electrons are moving from right to left and \$ J_p = 2 \frac{A}{m^2} \$ mean that holes are moving from left to right?

I just want to make sure if I am understanding the convention right. I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Impossible to say. Who defined what \$J_n\$ and \$J_p\$ were originally?

Comment: @Andyaka Are there different conventions for \$ J_n  \$ and \$ J_p  \$? I am using Neaman's book

Comment: @user207787 This sounds like a "chapter 1" question. But I'm not sure. Is this about a the case where a non-uniform concentration in a semiconductor (something you cannot get with a metal) where the concentration of holes (for example) varies with distance and there is therefore a *gradient*? Or am I completely off-base?